# perf: 'sched' is not a perf-command with perf 6.5.3 on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: linux, performance, ubuntu, perf, ubuntu-22.04

I am trying to find which processes are causing context switches within my application. Google returned this guide:

https://www.brendangregg.com/perf.html#SchedulerAnalysis

[image]

Great? I run it, but it doesn't work:

```
sudo perf record ./Test
[ perf record: Captured and wrote 1.438 MB perf.data (37217 samples) ]
perf sched latency
perf: 'sched' is not a perf-command. See 'perf --help'.
```

What's going wrong?

Comment: Presumably you have a version of `perf` from before `perf sched` was added.  `perf` 6.5 on my Arch Linux system has it, and I think it's been around for at least a year or so.

Comment: You can also record the software events that `perf sched` uses yourself:

`$ sudo perf record -e sched:sched_switch ./Test`

(`perf sched record` uses a number of other events as well, but if you only care about context switches, that may be sufficient for you.)

Then, you can use `perf script` to display the (fairly raw) event stream.

Comment: @PeterCordes My version is 6.5.3 though

Comment: @ThinkOpenly I'm trying to discover what exactly is my thread being swapped for. I can see there are context switches using `getrusage` but I'd like to understand what is causing it.

Comment: How did you install `perf`, on what distro?  Perhaps `perf sched` is optional and your distro package didn't configure it?  I'm `perf --version` `6.5-1` on Arch GNU/Linux, and the command is present for me.  According to `strace perf sched latency`, it just looks for some libraries whose names don't include `sched` or `latency` so I don't think any missing files could explain your results.

Comment: @PeterCordes Ubuntu 22.04. Installing it wasn't so simple but is there anything besides version I can run to help answer your question?

Comment: @PeterCordes `perf --version` returns `perf version 6.5.3`

Comment: I think Ubuntu doesn't build perf with many dependencies included. I'm also on Ubuntu 22.04, and `perf sched` does not work, nor does my earlier suggestion `perf record -e sched:sched_switch`.

That being said, you can download the linux source and build `perf` yourself. I had to install `libelf-dev` and `libtraceevent-dev` in order for perf to be able to provide the above two functions.

Comment: @ThinkOpenly thank you for confirming this. Please do put it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

I think Ubuntu doesn't build `perf` with many dependencies included. For example, `perf sched` and `perf record -e [software tracepoint]` require `libtraceevent`. Ubuntu has chose to disable those features rather than adopt the dependency.

I'm also on Ubuntu 22.04, and `perf sched` does not work, nor does my earlier suggestion `perf record -e sched:sched_switch`.

That being said, you can download the kernel source and build `perf` yourself. I had to install `libelf-dev` and `libtraceevent-dev` in order for `perf` to be able to provide the above two functions.

1. Install kernel source

   ```
   $ /usr/bin/sudo apt install linux-source
   ```

   Source shows up as a tarball in `/usr/src/`.
2. Untar kernel source somewhere

   ```
   $ cd [some-working-directory]
   $ tar -xf /usr/src/linux-source*
   $ cd linux-source-*
   ```
3. Copy in the current kernel config file

   ```
   $ cp /boot/config-$(uname -r) ./.config
   ```
4. Validate the config file against the linux source tree

   ```
   $ make oldconfig
   ```
5. Build and install perf to a local directory

   ```
   $ cd tools/perf
   $ make prefix=[some-working-directory]/install install
   ```

Afterwards, you should have a new `perf` binary in `[some-working-directory]/install/bin`. There are probably some caveats for how to make use of it properly from that location, but just running it seems to work for basic use.